# Readonly transactions with Neo4j

Tags: spring, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

Are there any benefits of using Spring `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` with Neo4j/Neo4j Spring Data ? Should I mark readonly transactions as `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SDN 4.2 (4.2.RC1 at the time of writing) you can use read only transactions.

> As of SDN 4.2 you can also define read only transactions.
>
> You can start a read only transaction by marking a class or method with @Transactional(readOnly=true).

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/#_read_only_transactions

Answer (score 1):

Transactions marked as readonly are routed to the follower / read-replica nodes in Neo4j. This reduces the load on the leader node(s), allowing them to better serve Write queries.